# Is there a word used for abstract space constructs?

Tags: terminology, history

Abstract space constructs like not actual space, but an abstract set of data organized in a space-like structure, like a 2 dimensional array or 3 dimensional array, where let's say x represents "item order" (ex: 1,2,3,4,5), y represents "item category" (ex: car, films, animals), and z represents "number of subcategories" (ex: 23, 15, 399). Is there a word for it? Philosophers dealing with ideas, I would guess there's such a word, but I haven't seen any philosopher ever create or use such a word before.

Comment: We don't need an extra word, we can just call them spaces. But manifolds, point-sets, algebras, topologies, and other things also can variously fit.

Comment: This are called [tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) in mathematics, but their use is not specific to philosophy or particularly interesting philosophically.